# pipenv setup in PyCharm doesn´t load bash variables

Tags: python, pycharm, dependencies, pipenv

I have some problems with PyCharm to create a pipenv environment for my project.

If I run *pipenv install* in my terminal works perfectly, also in a docker container, so I know is only an issue in PyCharm. When I add a new PipEnv environment in PyCharm, fails because I use some environment variables (that I have in my zsh and bash profiles) to load some "eggs" dependencies.

I checked in the PyCharm terminal, and I can print the value of my variables, but it fails when PyCharm launch it as subprocess. I also added manually in the **Tools/Terminal/Enviroment Variables** inside PyCharm settings, but it didn´t work. I closed the program, and also restarted the computer, and still no effect.

Any idea where should I set up them? It works in the pass, but no longer, but in this time I changed PyCharm version, and even the laptop, but I am not the only one in with this issue.

Comment: I found a workaround by installing the [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) plugin. Enable the plugin for the run configuration and add the `.env` file.